# Oracle Cloud : Issue to deploy python function using Cloud Shell

Tags: python, docker, deployment, oracle-cloud-functions, oracle-cloud-shell

I want to create a **python function** with **Oracle Cloud's function service**.
To do this, I'm following the `Getting started` tutorial using **Cloud Shell Setup**.
I follow all the steps as indicated, but when I come to deploy the function with the command `fn -v deploy --app DBDB_IO_Refresher`.
I get this error :

```
Fn: error running docker build: Cannot create/use builder instance docker for oci_fn_builder : exit status 125
```

Here are all the instructions I followed:

```
fn list context
fn use context eu-marseille-1
fn update context oracle.compartment-id ocid1.********************
fn update context registry ***********/func-python
docker login -u '***********' mrs.ocir.io
fn list apps
fn init --runtime java hello-test-python
cd hello-test-python
fn -v deploy --app DBDB_IO_Refresher
```

Here are the **details** of the error:

```
Deploying hello-test-python to app: DBDB_IO_Refresher
Bumped to version 0.0.2
Using Container engine docker
Building image ******/******/func-python/hello-test-python:0.0.2 
Dockerfile content
-----------------------------------
FROM fnproject/fn-java-fdk-build:jdk17-1.0.182 as build-stage
WORKDIR /function
ENV MAVEN_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts= -Dmaven.repo.local=/usr/share/maven/ref/repository
ADD pom.xml /function/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "package", "dependency:copy-dependencies", "-DincludeScope=runtime", "-DskipTests=true", "-Dmdep.prependGroupId=true", "-DoutputDirectory=target", "--fail-never"]
ADD src /function/src
RUN ["mvn", "package"]
FROM fnproject/fn-java-fdk:jre17-1.0.182
WORKDIR /function
COPY --from=build-stage /function/target/*.jar /function/app/
CMD ["com.example.fn.HelloFunction::handleRequest"]
-----------------------------------
FN_REGISTRY:  *****/*******/func-python
Current Context:  eu-marseille-1
TargetedPlatform:  amd64_arm64HostPlatform:  amd64


Fn: error running docker build: Cannot create/use builder instance docker for oci_fn_builder : exit status 125
```

Here is the docker configuration on CLoud Shell Setup :

```
pierre_ant@cloudshell:hello-test-python (eu-marseille-1)$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.11-ol
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.16.2
 Git commit:        9bb540d
 Built:             Fri Jul 23 01:33:55 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11-ol
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.2
  Git commit:       9bb540d
  Built:            Fri Jul 23 01:32:08 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
  Default Registry: docker.io
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.4.8
  GitCommit:        7eba5930496d9bbe375fdf71603e610ad737d2b2
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

And here is the Fn configuration:

```
pierre_ant@cloudshell:hello-test-python (eu-marseille-1)$ fn version
Client version is latest version: 0.6.28
Server version:  ?
```

If anyone has any ideas or needs further information, please don't hesitate, I've been stuck for over a week and can't find any solutions on the web.

Comment: I  have the exact same issue. What happens when you run the command: "docker-buildx version"?
I get bash: docker-buildx: command not found. 
I understand that the "Latest version of Fn requires to have a recent version of Docker engine and docker-buildx plugin installed" but I haven't been able to get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The solution we found is to select shape "Generic_X86" (not X86_ARM nor ARM) when creating an Fn application at the OCI console like so:
[image: Image showing what to select].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply.  As seen in the above image, I chose Generic_X86 shape for Fn application and solve the issue.

But, my coworker encounted same issue even if he chose generic_X86 for Fn app shape. We spent a long time trying to find a solution and eventually, we identified it.

FN application shape and Cloud shell VM architecture should match.
x86-64 for FN app and X86-64 for cloud shell.  OR ARM for FN app and ARM for cloud shell.

Hope it helps.